# How to handle update based on multiple column for spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have following entity for spring boot

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable
@Entity
@Table
public class AccessContact implements Persistable{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="ac_id")
    long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="contact_id")
    Contact contact;

    long reqId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    Role role;

    @CreatedDate
    LocalDateTime createDate;

}
```

I want to perform update operation if I get same `role_id`, `contact_id`,I see there is `UniqueContraints` but I think it will give error if I get same `role_id`, `contact_id` , can anyone please let me know how can I do that?

**Edit 1:**
I see from spring repository document *isNew* method which basically decides if entity is new or not
so below is my updated example

```
@Entity
@Table
public class AccessContact{
    AccessRepository accessRepo
    @Id
    @Column(name="ac_id")
    long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="contact_id")
    Contact contact;

    long reqId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    Role role;

    @CreatedDate
    LocalDateTime createDate;

   @Transient
   public boolean isNew(){
     AccessContact accessContact = accessRepo.findContactByContactAnsRole(contact, role);}
     if(accessContact == null)
       return true;

     return false;
   }
}
```

my *AccessRepository* looks like this

```
@Repository
public interface AccessRepository extends JpaRepository<AccessContact, Long>{
  public AccessContact findContactByContactAnsRole(Contact c, Role r);
}
```

but I don't know if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: is there any issue with jparepository.save()?

Comment: yes, it works only with primary key, it is creating duplicate records for same role,email

Comment: What do you mean you want to perform an update "if I get same role_id, contact_id"? JPA entities are _managed entities_, so any change to an entity (while it is managed and not detached) will be propagated to the database.
Or are you saying you are receiving a detached entity or DTO, e.g., some JSON and you want to perform an _insert OR update_?

Comment: Also, this is NOT a good implementation of `isNew`. Check out: https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-state-detection/
(I'm not sure why you'd need this at all)

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer : whatever you said is correct, due to repetition I didn't add my DTO object, but yes I do receive it and I want to perform insert or update based on that

Answer (score 0):

@BenjaminMaurer have right, you need to get entry from DB, if not found then save your entry, and if found, then put values from your entry to entry from DB and save. In this case `jparepository.save()` will be working just as you expected.

Entry from DB is managed by e.g Hibernate, and your entry mayt be not. This is why you need to do it in that way and why `jparepository.save()` wasn't working as you expected.

Maybe think about getting entry from db while mapping (using AccessRepository) instead of using `new AccessContact()`